# Http Error 500 in wordpress digital ocean

Tags: php, html, wordpress, digital-ocean

There is a mining script. then, i have try to remove it & after that yeah, the website is down until now.
Here my website = http://awmun.org/

i use divi theme for my website

i just got error on my website.here is i attach the error.

```
[30-Jan-2018 09:03:55 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:03:56 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:04:10 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:04:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:04:44 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:05:28 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:05:29 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:05:59 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$w2c1f100' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1
[30-Jan-2018 09:06:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function current_theme_supports() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(294): create_initial_taxonomies()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-config.php(93): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#2 /var/www/html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#3 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
#4 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/w...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 149
[30-Jan-2018 09:06:41 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''custom_css' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1645
[30-Jan-2018 09:06:41 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''custom_css' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1645
```

Comment: Well there are the errors, you already know what's wrong

Comment: but I've tried fix but still error

Comment: Clear the logs, try accessing the website and check the logs again, you'll see what causes the problem, are you sure you fixed all the errors shown in the logs?

Comment: i have try to remove the error on line 1

Comment: What is your line 1 in theme.php?

Comment: line 1 in theme.php >> unknown Script,like script mining.i delete it

Comment: taxonomy.php on line 149 nothing wrong on this script

Comment: Update your word-press Version using FTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow these steps to resolve this issue ::

1. Deactivating WordPress Plugins
2. Auditing Web Server Logs by using this command :

   tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

In your case you should check the `custom css` file and make the correct path in `line 1 in theme.php`

Answer (score 0):

Bow in your site is all garbage, so you need to delete the extras plugin and check the speed of the site and css minify, js minify Have to do